# Call Static Page in ZF2?

Tags: php, zend-framework2

i want to add pdf file and also video link in my current site. both pdf file and video are static. how can i configure it with my current site .There is no need to add controller and action for it.so i install PhlySimplePage module in vendor folder but cant got any idea how to use it.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You mean to create a static link into a view script? To use a module like PhlySimplePage is a great idea, show us what you try with this module or just print <a href='yourUrl.pdf'>link</a> in your view script.

Comment: I want to use this code <a class="dem" href="demo.html">demo</a> but its cant work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easy way it to put the  link link in your view script.
But please note, that the file has to be in the public folder, and the url has to be abosulute, or relative to /public/.

Also, you can create a route even for static files, if you want to keep it tidy